# Angular 8 animation slide left and right like carousel

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, frameworks

I have a problem to create a sort of carousel with Angular animations. It is for a signing up form with different steps. When you go to the next step, it has to slide from the right, when you go back, it slides from the left.

I didn't manage to create a plnkr example, impossible to import Angular animations, sorry.

Here a basic code to give you an idea of what I'm looking for:

```
animations: [
trigger('slideRight', [
  state('in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
  state('out', style({ transform: 'translateX(+100%)' })),
  transition('in <=> out', animate('200ms ease-in')),
  transition('out <=> in', animate('200ms ease-in-out'))
]),
trigger('slideLeft', [
  state('in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
  state('out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' })),
  transition('in <=> out', animate('200ms ease-in')),
  transition('out <=> in', animate('200ms ease-in-out'))
])
]

signingUpStep: 0;


<div>
  <div [hidden]="signingUpStep != 0" [@slideLeft]="signingUpStep == 0 ? 'in' : 'out'">
    <div>Step 0</div>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="signingUpStep != 1" [@slideRight]="signingUpStep == 1 ? 'in' : 'out'">
    <div>Step 1</div>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="signingUpStep != 2" [@slideRight]="signingUpStep == 2 ? 'in' : 'out'">
    <div>Step 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is with:

```
<div [hidden]="signingUpStep != 1" [@slideRight]="signingUpStep == 1 ? 'in' : 'out'">
    <div>Step 1</div>
</div>
```

It always uses [@slideRight] animation whereas I would like it to indeed use [@slideRight] when the user comes from signingUpStep == 0, but use [@slideLeft] when the user comes from signingUpStep == 2.

Like the middle div signingUpStep == 1 was in the middle of a carousel.

I read about :increment and :decrement but I'm not sure about how to use them.

I also tried to used the params but it doesn't work like I want. I need to be able to dynamically change the params depending upon the user position in the slide.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem and managed to do it with only one animation trigger using a parameter:

```
 trigger('slideInOut', [
  transition(':enter', [
    style({ transform: 'translateX({{direction}}%)' }),
    animate('400ms ease-in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' })),
  ]),
])
```

and on the template ( it's a data carousel, so I change the direction on navigation from Right to Left to Left to Right ) :

```
 <div class="envolvido"
 *ngFor="let envolvido of itensPaginaAtual; index as indexOfelement"
 [@slideInOut]="{ value: '', 
 params: { direction: this.direction === 'RL' ? '100' : '-100' } }"
>
```

Comment: sometime ago I make a carousel "style bootstrap" using animation in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402216/custom-animated-image-slider-in-angular/70403362#70403362), perhaf can be on help

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the solution involves using `:increment` and `:decrement`. The idea is that you have a counter which increments when the carousel moves forwards, and decrements when it goes back. This gives you the state changes that your transitions can hook into. You also need to use the `query()` function to capture the slides entering and exiting the carousel, and the `group()` function to ensure that the entering and exiting animations run in parallel.

see demo at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-required-text-component-dqhky1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.ts)

carousel.component.ts

```
import { Component, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  style,
  animate,
  transition,
  query,
  group,
} from '@angular/animations';

const ANIMATION_TIMING = '600ms ease-out';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.css'],

  animations: [
    trigger('trigger', [
      transition(':increment', [
        group([
          query(
            ':enter',
            [
              style({ transform: 'translate(100%, 0)' }),
              animate(
                ANIMATION_TIMING,
                style({ transform: 'translate(0, 0)' })
              ),
            ],
            { optional: true }
          ),
          query(
            ':leave',
            [
              animate(
                ANIMATION_TIMING,
                style({ transform: 'translate(-100%, 0)' })
              ),
            ],
            { optional: true }
          ),
        ]),
      ]),
      transition(':decrement', [
        group([
          query(
            ':enter',
            [
              style({ transform: 'translate(-100%, 0)' }),
              animate(
                ANIMATION_TIMING,
                style({ transform: 'translate(0, 0)' })
              ),
            ],
            { optional: true }
          ),
          query(
            ':leave',
            [
              animate(
                ANIMATION_TIMING,
                style({ transform: 'translate(100%, 0)' })
              ),
            ],
            { optional: true }
          ),
        ]),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class CarouselComponent {
  @HostBinding('@trigger') public signingUpStep: number = 0;

  direction = '';

  onNavigate(event: string) {
    this.direction = event;
    if (this.direction === 'prev') {
      this.signingUpStep = Math.max(0, this.signingUpStep - 1);
    } else {
      // hardcoding the number of steps here - not the best!
      this.signingUpStep = Math.min(3, this.signingUpStep + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

carousel.component.html

```
<app-step
  [step]="signingUpStep"
  *ngIf="signingUpStep === 0"
  index="0"
  imageUrl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/22/Malus_domestica_a1.jpg/220px-Malus_domestica_a1.jpg"
  (navigate)="onNavigate($event)"
></app-step>

<app-step
  [step]="signingUpStep"
  *ngIf="signingUpStep === 1"
  index="1"
  imageUrl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4c/Bananas.jpg/1280px-Bananas.jpg"
  (navigate)="onNavigate($event)"
></app-step>

<app-step
  [step]="signingUpStep"
  *ngIf="signingUpStep === 2"
  index="2"
  imageUrl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c3/Carrots_at_Ljubljana_Central_Market.JPG/1920px-Carrots_at_Ljubljana_Central_Market.JPG"
  (navigate)="onNavigate($event)"
></app-step>

<app-step
  [step]="signingUpStep"
  *ngIf="signingUpStep === 3"
  index="3"
  imageUrl="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/Persea_americana_fruit_2.JPG/800px-Persea_americana_fruit_2.JPG"
  (navigate)="onNavigate($event)"
></app-step>
```

carousel.component.css

```
:host {
  display: block;
  border: solid 2px hotpink;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

step.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  HostBinding,
  Input,
  Output,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-step',
  templateUrl: './step.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./step.component.css'],
})
export class StepComponent {
  @Input() step: number;

  @Output() navigate: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  @Input() imageUrl: string = '';

  @HostBinding('style.backgroundImage') @Input() get backgroundImage() {
    return `url(${this.imageUrl})`;
  }

  clickNext() {
    this.navigate.emit('next');
  }

  clickPrev() {
    this.navigate.emit('prev');
  }
}
```

step.component.html

```
<h2>Step {{step}}</h2>

<!-- hard coding number of steps here - not the best! -->
<button *ngIf="step > 0" (click)="clickPrev()">Prev</button>
<button *ngIf="step < 3" (click)="clickNext()">Next</button>
```

step.component.css

```
:host {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```