# How to enable touch slider options of ng-bootstrap carousel for Angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel, ng-bootstrap

In my e-commerce website I have product images for which I have used [ng-bootstrap carousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/releases/10.x/#/components/carousel/examples) it works fine (besides the slow initial load issue) However does not support touch/swipe slide to right/left on mobile devices.

I wonder what's the best to either fix it, or an alternate lightweight package to make it work?

I know this problem is addressed in a few responses in past however most of them point to a Jquery-based solution, but I want to keep my solution clean without mix of libraries.

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

It's just enclosed in a div with the events touchstart and touchend

```
<div (touchstart)="posIni = $event.changedTouches[0].pageX"
      (touchend)="move($event.changedTouches[0].pageX)">
    <ngb-carousel #carousel *ngIf="images">
       ....
    </ngb-carousel>
</div>
```

Then use prev and next method of carousel

```
  @ViewChild('carousel') carousel:NgbCarousel
  posIni: any;
  move(pos:number) {
    const offset = this.posIni - pos;
    if (offset < -100) this.carousel.prev()

    if (offset > 100) this.carousel.next();
  }
```

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-52np99?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel-basic.ts)

NOTE: Really make a carousel it's easy, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70402216/custom-animated-image-slider-in-angular/70403362#70403362)